# Google sign in on android returning Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I'm developing an Android application and a web application to the same project. In both parts of the project i need to login with google account.

Firstly, when i just had a development environment everything was working correctly, both mobile and web.

Now, I add a second environment, the production environment and i configure a new url to my web application and a new endpoint to my API that connects to my android app. I created also a new google application, new credentials, added a new SHA-1key to the firebase application and downloaded a new google-services.json to my android project.
With the new keys, I can login in my web application throw my new google app but i can´t login in the android app. I just get this error:

`"Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}"`

After more research about this error, i tried a different approach. Create a new firebase application but was impossible because i need to use the same package name in both firebase applications and the firebase don't let me do it.

I'm a bit loss, what i'm i doing wrong? Some missing configuration? I really need some guidance.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you probably forgot something while setting it up and I know the error is useless. You can debug the issue by doing a few things.

- Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app.
- Make sure the SHA-1 key is correct in firebase.
- Make sure the package name in firebase-console matches the package name in your android app. For me, I refactored my package name and had to register a new android-app in Firebase console with a new google-services.json and it worked after that.
- Make sure you are providing the `web_client_id` in google sign in options like this:

  ```
  GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
  .requestEmail().requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
  .build();
  ```

Comment: Hi @parth-bhoiwala, thank you for your time. The same code work with different credentials. I just get the SHA-1 key from running the signningReport from gradle.  The GoogleSignInOptions is equals to yours. Have to be something else